# JQGrid Delete Row Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid`. When I want to `delete` row I am writing in console `$('#grid').jqGrid('delGridRow', 1);`. But this does `not` work it returns `false` as result. Did I missed something ?

Comment: Does second parameter (1) retrieved by $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow") function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the grid have no row with the rowid 1: no `<tr id="1">...</tr>` element. Either you don't filled the data of the row correctly (the data have to contains the values of `id` attribute) or you just mix the terminology of [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) with the rowid.

Comment: Thank you for give me a sign. I found the error. The parameter was passed as row id '5' not 'jqg5'. This fixed the problem.